# Is Windows' AcquireSRWLockExclusive recursive?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, readwritelock

I need to use read-write lock, but I would also like to be sure that the lock is recursive in both read and write mode, so that calling function that uses it on the same thread doesn't lock.

I found nothing on MSDN docs. Maybe it's hidden somewhere and I didn't find it?

Comment: This is clearly documented on the top page of the MSDN documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SRWLocks are not recursive, from [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/slim-reader-writer--srw--locks):

> An SRW lock is the size of a pointer. The advantage is that it is fast to update the lock state. The disadvantage is that very little state information can be stored, so **SRW locks cannot be acquired recursively**. In addition, a thread that owns an SRW lock in shared mode cannot upgrade its ownership of the lock to exclusive mode.

Comment: Thanks. The second part is really sad, I wanted to be able to upgrade the lock. That's like 70% of how I ever used RW locks in other libraries.